# Need a mock server for my custom HttpClient rest template to test with

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, integration-testing, mockserver

I have a custom authentication rest template my library returns which is HttpClient.  I need a library that will let me bind my rest template to the mock server so I can test my template.  I had high hopes for [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in .Net Core but  it has it's own `TestServer.CreateClient()` with special `HttpMessageHandler`.  Seems to be no way to use use my own rest template with that.  I use WireMock for some other basic canned request and response stuff but I really need to bind this template to my test server much like you would see in Java's MockRestSesrviceServer seen here.  https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot (section 2).

I've looked around a lot haven't found one that allow this type of binding in .NET Core.  I had high hopes for [mockhttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) but again, no way to bind with your own HttpClient it seems.  Have a missed it?  Is there a way to do this with TestServer or is there another lib out there I missed that will do this?  Thanks for any input.  It's been weeks on this.

I should mention this is lib/nuget package I'm working on so I don't have web startup classes built into the src project to test from.  I'd have to create anything  to seed webproject configs similar to a startup.cs, which Im willing to do if that will work.

Comment: Here comes another dust bunny award.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use MockServer in a container , TestServer gives pretty nasty long term results due to code build complexity and understanding becoming part of the tests

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) could help you in this scenario?

- HTTP response stubbing, matchable on URL/Path, headers, cookies and
  body content patterns
- Library can be used in unit tests and integration tests
- Runs as a standalone process, as windows service, as Azure/IIS or as docker
- Configurable via a fluent DotNet API, JSON files and JSON over HTTP
- Record/playback of stubs (proxying)
- Per-request conditional proxying
- Stateful behaviour simulation
- Response templating / transformation using Handlebars and extensions
- Can be used locally or in CI/CD scenarios.

Comment: I use wiremock for canned http requests and responses that doesn't require my template.